# check whether SD card is available or not in device programmatically for Windows Phone 'mango'

Tags: windows-phone-7, sd-card

In my application I want to check whether SD card is avaiable or not .If its available I want to to write a txt file on it and the read the same file

I have search so many thing,however didn't found any thing.

Plz help

Thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 2):

Windows Phone currently doesn't support SD cards specifically. There are a few mobile models with SD-Cards (e.g. by Samsung and HTC), but they are not officially accessible. Windows Phone is using a propritairy file format and using the internal storage and the "sd card"-storage (sometimes it's not a separate card but a flash IC on the board) as some kind of "RAID" together.

As long as Windows Phone doesn't support memory cards as a hardware specification, there will be no way to use it. ;)
Perhaps we can speculate if they will become available with Windows Phone vNext ("Apollo" / Windows Phone 8).

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that the SDK doesn't allow you to access any storage but the application Isolated Storage, you are unable to do what you require (not even know if a SD card is available or not!)